# (iOS) Increasing memory consumption related to GameScene

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

When a GameScene has been presented, there are two categories which constantly increase in number of persistent#: '_NSArrayM' and 'CAMetalDrawable'. Which results in memory consumption to increase at roughly 0.1 MB every 20 seconds. However, when I set SKView.isPaused = true, memory consumption stops increasing. Is this normal or even bad?
Additionally, how can I clear the persistent data?

[image: leak]

Answer (score 0):

If you're still looking for a solution, I had a similar issue.

If you edit scheme and disable Metal API Validation and GPU frame capture, it seemed to fix it for me.